# Select first and last element on a column (time format) gnuplot

Tags: time, format, row, gnuplot, multiple-columns

I am performing statistics with Gnuplot on several files, each with a large numbers of rows and columns, first of them in time format "%H:%M:%S". I've found here (sorry, cannot find the link) a way to easily do the process, that is:

```
# converts the time string in column COL to a number of seconds
intime(COL) = strptime("%H:%M:%S",strcol(1))

# finds correlation of time (seconds) in col 1 with the value in col 2
startrange0 = strptime("%H:%M:%S","18:46:27")
endrange0 = strptime("%H:%M:%S","23:59:27")

stats [startrange0:endrange0] 'datafile.txt' u (intime(1)):2 prefix "A"
set print outfilename append
```

My problem here is that I have to access to each file to write the starting and ending time exactly in the code, which *breaks* a bit the automation of the script.

The question is, is there a way to access the first and last element of the time column (that is, the "18:46:27" and the "23:59:27" in the example), so it can read it form each file?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I understand something wrong: If you want to evaluate the complete file, why do you need to specify the range `[startrange0:endrange0]` in the `stats` command?

Comment: Thanks for your question, it is true that I might not need it in the stats command, but for some reason, if I remove the `startrange0 = strptime("%H:%M:%S","18:46:27")`
`endrange0 = strptime("%H:%M:%S","23:59:27")` lines, file crashes. Besides, eventually I need to delimit ranges of the file (for example when times cross midnight)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bit of a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since OP doesn't describe the whole story.
But from the title it seems to be clear that OP want's to have the first and last value of a (time)column. Why, and in which format, and for what exact purpose stays unclear.

The following script makes sure that you take only the very first value (in case you have data with double empty lines) by using the pseudocolumns `-2` and `0`  (check `help pseudocolumns`).

**Data:** `SO45233771.dat`

```
18:46:27    0.111
19:00:00    1.222
20:00:00    2.333
21:00:00    3.444


22:00:00    4.555
22:30:00    5.666
23:00:00    6.777
23:46:27    7.888
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### get first and last time value from a column
reset

FILE = "SO45233771.dat"

myFmt = "%H:%M:%S"
stats [*:*] FILE u ( column(-2)==0 && column(0)==0 ? s0=strcol(1) : 0, s1=strcol(1)) nooutput

print s0, ' = ', strptime(myFmt,s0)
print s1, ' = ', strptime(myFmt,s1)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
18:46:27 = 67587.0
23:46:27 = 85587.0
```